# Script or command to increment number in file name inside file

Tags: regex, bash, perl, unix

I have a file in which we have entries in following format. I would like to increment the numbers in file names inside this file. So `some_v1.png` will become `some_v2.png`. Is there a way with regex OR command line utility to achieve this.

Following is example file (file.config) with file entries as string.

```
something/some_v1.png
something/some_v4.png
something/some_v3.png
```

Comment: If you're looking to rename (move) the files, be careful not to overwrite existing files when you do this!

Comment: It can be done with perl perl -i -p -e 's/(\d+)/$1 + 1/eg' filename thanks for help

Comment: Why not use a for loop and do like `for i in {1..5}; do echo 'something/some_v'$i ; done`

Comment: @PruthviRaj cannot do this as the numbers are not in sequence. Some file entries are already on higher versions

Comment: @AnilNamde , well your question said `increment` :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like a great match for awk's "split" function:

```
awk '{n=split($0,a,"[1-9][0-9]*",s);for(i=1;i<n;++i)printf "%s%d",a[i],s[i]+1;print a[n]}'
```

The perl one-liner you already found also works great, with one exception: files with leading-zero numbers will lose the zeroes. Here is a fix for that using the magical auto-increment:

```
perl -pe 's/(\d+)/++($a=$1)/eg'
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to rename a bunch of files I'd use an auxiliary directory and a test to see if there is an actual file to rename.

```sh
mkdir aux
for i in {1..7} ; do
    j=$($i + 1)
    [ -f something/some_v${i}.png ] && mv something/some_v${i}.png aux/some_v${j}.png
done
mv aux/* something
rmdir aux
```

The use of a fixed name for the auxiliary directory could not stand a security review for repeated use in a dynamic production environment but I think it's fine for a one shot use in a controlled environment.

Answer (score 1):

In `perl`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;

foreach
    my $filename ( 
    sort { $b =~ s/.*(\d+).*/$1/r <=> $a =~ s/.*(\d+).*/$1/r }
    glob "something/some_v*.png" )
{
    chomp $filename;
    if ( my ($vnum) = $filename =~ m/(\d+)\.png/ ) {
        print "mv $filename ", $filename =~ s|\d+\.png|++$vnum.".png"|re,
            "\n";
    }
}
```

Note - sorting numerically, to ensure that you're never replacing 5 with 4, before you've renamed 5.